# VBA data type equivalent to a long number access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Access 2016 has added support for 64 integer (bigint) in tables and especially linked tables. But what is the best corresponding VBA data type.

I hope it is obvious that I want to transfer values between variables and fields in the tables.

Long is too small and a varant decimal seems rather too big. Is there any sensible type I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've missed the [LongLong data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/longlong-data-type).

Note that this data type is only valid in 64-bit Office applications. You can use conditional compilation to use the decimal data type on 32-bits applications, or not support certain functionality on 32-bits applications.

```
#If Win64 Then
    myVariant = CLngLng(rs!MyBigInt)
#Else
    myVariant = CDec(rs!MyBigInt)
#End If
```

You can use `LongPtr` to have a `LongLong` on 64-bits, and a `Long` on 32-bits, but that would cause problems when working with large BigInts on 32-bits.

Comment: OK, thanks. Using 64bit Office is an issue. Shame there isn't one for 32 Office. But you seem to be saying that for 32 bit office Decimal is the one to go with.

Comment: Yes, if you're only working with 32-bits Office, Decimal is the way to go. But you can just use variants, especially since you can't declare a variable as a decimal. A decimal is a type that can only be stored as a variant. If you retrieve the value from a recordset, you can just assume it has the right type (and you can't avoid the tiny memory overhead that using a variant has).